# Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). Firebase error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase";
require("firebase/firestore")
const firebaseConfig = {
 *configuration*
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();
export { firebase, db as default };
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by deleting the firebase configuration from the index file